# nuxt3 directives are not included and not defined although using exact docs method

Tags: nuxtjs3

Trying to use custom directives in nuxtjs.
Using the exact configurations that is used on the docs:
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins/#vue-directives

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.directive('myd', {
        mounted (el) {
        vel.focus()
    },
    getSSRProps (binding, vnode) {
         // you can provide SSR-specific props here
        return {}
    }
})
```

And then in a component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-myd="'tmp'"></div>
   </div>
</template>
```

I've also tried different combination of naming (such as myd, v-myd).

I've also tried tried w/o nuxt.config.ts

```
  plugins: [
    {src: '~/plugins/myd.client', mode: 'client'},
  ]
```

No matter what I do I keep receiving the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: myd                                                                   12:27:00
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot read property 'getSSRProps' of undefined                       12:27:00
  at Module.ssrGetDirectiveProps (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:482:42)
  at _sfc_ssrRender (./components/MessageBubble.vue:228:225)
  at renderComponentSubTree (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:710:17)
  at renderComponentVNode (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:644:16)
  at Module.ssrRenderComponent (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:94:12)
  at ./components/Conversation.vue:283:42
  at Module.ssrRenderList (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:443:13)
  at ./components/Conversation.vue:281:34
  at Module.ssrRenderList (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:443:13)
  at ./components/Conversation.vue:273:32
```

Tried both Nuxt 3.2.0 and 3.2.2

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13382#issuecomment-1397298727

based on the 2nd line of your error log

Answer (score -1):

```
{src: '~/plugins/myd.client', mode: 'all'},
```